# Chrome extension - get tab url in context menu onClicked event when used on PDF document

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which adds a context menu item. When clicked, one of the things it needs to do is get the URL of the page that it was clicked on. This is dead easy for most pages, because you can just use tab.url in the `onClicked` event.

When used on PDF documents, this is a bit more difficult because the value of `tab.url` is
`chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/` - the built in chrome extension which handles PDF files.

I am currently achieving this by using a content script.

In my manifest I have the following:

```
   {
       "run_at": "document_end",
       "matches": ["*://*/*.pdf"],
       "js": ["pdfcontentscript.js"]
   }
 ],
```

and the content script gets the URL and puts it into local storage:

pdfcontentscript.js:

`chrome.storage.local.set({ 'pdfUrl': document.location.href }, function () {});`

The problem is that doing it like this means the extension requires the 'Host' permission, which means it takes several days to go through the store validation process. It feels like I really shouldn't need hosts permission because all I am doing is trying to get the activeTab url that the user has clicked my extension on.

The other thing I have tried was to use `tabs.executeScript()` to try and execute a script to get the URL of the PDF. This works on HTML web pages, but on PDFs it throws an error "Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host" - I think the reason for this error is because of what is being explained in the comments on this post: [Permissions for modifying DOM in Chrome extension context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701095/permissions-for-modifying-dom-in-chrome-extension-context-menu)

I have also tried getting the url of the active tab, as follows:

```
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
          }, ([currentTab]) => {
            alert(currentTab.url);
          });
```

Unfortunately, this works ok on HTML pages, but on PDFs the url is `undefined`
I also tried this with `lastFocusedWindow: true` instead of `currentWindow: true` and got the same result.

So, my question is: In a Chrome extension, when the context menu is clicked on a PDF how can I get the URL of that PDF without having to have Host permission?

Comment: A context menu cannot be invoked in inactive/backgrounded tab by a human so just get the active tab's URL.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm - I've just added details above about what happens when I try this.

Comment: The code is correct and it works for PDF. Since it doesn't for you, I guess you're doing it while devtools window is open and focused, which is a known bug in Chrome, see [Chrome tabs query returning empty tab array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886442).

Comment: Oh, maybe you don't have `tabs` permission, which is unfortunately needed for this.

Comment: thanks very much for your help @wOxxOm - you are correct, I just needed to add the `tabs` permission. Any idea why it needs that for it to work on a PDF, when it works without it for a normal web page?

Comment: It's a bug: https://crbug.com/1125079